# Erro General error: 1449 ao buscar registros Banco MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Estou obtendo o erro abaixo ao fazer SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM vn_horario_view;
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer ('root'@'localhost') does not exist

Como resolver este erro?

Comment: Só isso no erro ? Não saiu mais nada ?

Comment: Complementei a mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você importou os objetos de outro banco de dados pode ter perdido algum `DEFINER`.

Tente:

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER DEFINER=`youruser`@`host` VIEW ", 
table_name, " AS ", view_definition, ";") 
FROM information_schema.views 
WHERE table_schema='your-database-name';
```

Você também pode criar um novo usuário dando a ele acesso total, se tudo correr corretamente você deleta o root e muda o nome do novo user para root (Gambiarra)!

Mesmo problema no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist)

Comment: Obrigado Junior. Resolvido !